# Calculating the electron orbital for the following (4, 1, -1, -1/2)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, orbitals

I'm fairly new to applications in physics, so would really appreciate your support on whether I performed the following calculation for this orbital correctly. Also, what does it mean when $\pm\frac{1}{2}$?

(4, 1, -1, -1/2)

Given n = 4, and l = 1 then this only goes to P.

I'm slightly confused on where to go next, any help is greatly appreciated!

I'm not entirely sure about the $\pm\frac{1}{2}$, though I'm assuming this is $4p$?

Comment: *the following calculation* Calculation of what? You don’t seem to have calculated anything.

Comment: The four quantum numbers are presumably $(n,l,m,m_s)$.

Comment: @G.Smith I think this is what he wants: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/hydwf.html

Comment: @Gert But that doesn’t seem consistent with asking “whether I performed the following calculation for this orbital correctly”.

Comment: @G.Smith Consistency? Now you're asking for a lot! ;-) Seems to me many OPs are unsure of what it is they want to ask...

Comment: @Gert Many OPs ignore comments also. I guess that they don’t understand that many comments are an attempt to get them to clarify the question before it gets closed as unclear.